# Error in numpy.linalg.solve when trying to calculate exact solution

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I am trying to calculate A^-1*x and i am using the command:

```
Solution = numpy.linalg.solve(A, x)
```

A is: ndarray 2000x2000: 4000000 elems, type `float64`, 32000000 bytes (30 Mb)

x is: ndarray  2000: 2000 elems, type `float64`, 16000 bytes

The error i am getting is the following:

```
----> 1 Solution = np.linalg.solve(A, x)

/Users/glazar0/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.pyc in solve(a, b)
    379     signature = 'DD->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'dd->d'
    380     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 381     r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    382 
    383     return wrap(r.astype(result_t))

/Users/glazar0/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.pyc in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     88 
     89 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 90     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     91 
     92 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Comment: Is the matrix singular?  Singular matrices do not have inverses (you can, if I recall correctly, take the pseudoinverse [of a singular matrix])

Comment: Yes , It does not have inverse

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is indeed singular (i.e. non-invertible) then there is no unique solution for `b` in `Ab = x`. However, you can still solve for `b` in the least-squares sense using [`np.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

```
b, residuals, rank, singular_vals = np.linalg.lstsq(A, x)
```

Comment: (this was the pseudoinverse I was referring to)

Comment: @Foon Yeah kind of, except `lstsq` does not explicitly compute the pseudo-inverse (it calls the `dgelsd` LAPACK routine, which I believe uses the SVD method described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods))

Comment: @ali_m: numpy.linalg.lstsq uses the LAPACK routine gesv, based on LU decomposition. scipy.linalg.lstsq uses gelsd, based on SVD.
SVD is slower but more robust to numerical round-off errors.

Comment: @user2051916 I'm pretty sure that `np.linalg.lstsq` also uses `*gelsd`: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1957. Perhaps you're confusing it with `np.linalg.solve`, which does use `*gesv`: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1579.